# Android Google Maps Linkify Phone Number in Snippet

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, linkify

I am trying to linkify a phone number within a snippet of a google map. Given this code:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapPane extends Activity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Sydney")
                .snippet("1-800-555-5555")
                .position(sydney));
    }
}
```

How could I make thie snippet:

```
.snippet("1-800-555-5555")
```

Linkified, so if they click the marker, then click the phone number in the resulting snippet popup, Android will call that number?

Comment: I doubt that's possible. When you create your own `InfoWindowAdapter`, the `View` you return for the popup is converted into a bitmap, and the bitmap, not the `View`, is what's shown. Hence, interactive elements in the `View` are pointless. I assume that the default "info window" popups are created the same way.

Comment: I didn't know that InfoWindows are converted to a bitmap, very interesting.   @user what you could do is make the phone number styled like a link (blue and underlined), and then implement an InfoWindow click listener.